# How did I get an "Unsave this answer" flag?

Tags: support

Earlier I wrote and posted an answer to this question:

[Order of prepositions "of" and "by"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/600454/order-of-prepositions-of-and-by)

Somehow, in the process of making one or two edits almost immediately, the flag under the *Downvote* triangle changed colour, with the mouseover message "*Unsave this answer*".

There is nothing in this site's help information to explain this feature.

So my questions:

- What triggered this flag, which has never happened before?
- How is "*Unsaving*" different from *Edit*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Saves are the new Bookmarks. (Or, since you've been here a while, they're just like Favorites were.) But they're better! What that means is that you can create organized, searchable lists of posts (use the `in:saves` search operator). Yes, you can save answers too. If you're saving someone else's post, you won't get inbox notifications from it (that's what following is for).

It has nothing to do with editing. You just misclicked.

You can manage your Saves in [your profile](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/saves/current/all). It's the tab at the top that says "Saves".

See
[Bookmarks have evolved into Saves](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/382019/323179)

Comment: In other words, the saving in question is saving in a particular user's 'private' list of the posts that the user is specially interested in, rather than, as the OP reasonably assumed, on the publicly displayed parts of the site. That is a very confusing way of using *save*.

Comment: @jsw29 Yup, and a lot of people said how much they hated the name when it first came out. "Bookmarks" was better but I guess they didn't want to reuse the name. (I guess it's better than "favorites" since a lot of people have lists of posts they don't like but want to follow up with.)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.